# TypeScript: Is it possible to derive a type that lists the attribute names and types of another object type?

Tags: typescript

If I have a TypeScript type like

```js
type O = { strKey: string; numKey: number; boolKey: boolean };
```

is it possible to define a type definition `NameValue` such that `NameValue<O>` would create the new type

```js
type OAttrs =
 | { name: "strKey"; value: string }
 | { name: "numKey"; value: number }
 | { name: "boolKey"; value: boolean };
```

This could be useful when using `Object.fromEntries` to create an object of type `O` from a list of attributes, for example.

Two attempts that don't work.

This first attempt is not legal TypeScript.

```js
// export type NameValue1<T> = { name: P extends keyof T, value: T[P] };
// Cannot find name 'P'. ts(2304)
```

The second attempt does not succeed in making the `value` type specific to the corresponding `name`.

```js
export type NameValue2P<T, P extends keyof T> = { name: P; value: T[P] };
export type NameValue2<T> = NameValue2P<T, keyof T>;

export type ONameValue2 = NameValue2<O>;
// type ONameValue2 = {
//   name: keyof O;
//   value: string | number | boolean;
// }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which maps over the properties of `O`. Afterwards, you can index the mapped type with `keyof O` producing the desired union.

```
type NameValue<O> = {
  [K in keyof O]: {
    name: K,
    value: O[K]
  }
}[keyof O]
```

```
type OAttrs = NameValue<O>

// type OAttrs = {
//     name: "strKey";
//     value: string;
// } | {
//     name: "numKey";
//     value: number;
// } | {
//     name: "boolKey";
//     value: boolean;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeUDOwBOBpCIBcamAlgHYDmA3FCQK4C2O+19ARhBlSwPZcA2jBbnwgBDElAC+FAFDTQkKADkRdCADURvGhAA8MAHwJk0qFADaWKKSgBrXFwBmsALoEkJ09RUQCWADQepgBumtoEMBbOHhLSEmZ2II4usvLQMACCwJioRsqqGlq6BkA)